# Week Day Starting from a Certain Day (01 Jan 2021) in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, week-number

I am trying to get week numbers in a Year starting from a certain day
I've checked the stack but quite confused.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01'),
       extract('year' from TIMESTAMP '2021-01-01')
```

The output is 53|2021

I want it to be 01|2021

I understand the principle of the isoweek but I want the year to start in 01-01-2021

The aim is to use intervals from this day to determine week numbers

```
Week N0| End Date
     1 | 01-01-2021
     2 | 01-08-2021
     5 | 01-29-2021
...
```

Comment: Apparently you are missing the point of ISO week. The ISO week **always** begins on Monday, but you are wanting to start on Friday - not happening. Further the first week of the ISO year is Monday on or before 4-Jan.  This leads to sometimes unexpected results as the beginning days in Jan may be in the last week of the prior calendar year, or the last days is Dec being in the first calendar week of the next calendar year.

Comment: The expression `extract( 'week' from somedate)`  returns the ISO week number, to be consistent you need `extract('isoweek' from somedate)` . So for your data: select extract('week' from date '2021-01-01'), extract( 'isoyear' from date '2021-01-01'); As @a_horse_with_no_name indicates for any other week determination you need to calculate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really strange way to determine the week number, but in the end it's a simple math operation: the number of days since January first divided by 7.

You can create a function for this:

```
create function custom_week(p_input date)
  returns int
as
$$
   select (p_input - date_trunc('year', p_input)::date) / 7 + 1;
$$
language sql
immutable;
```

So this:

```
select date, custom_week(date)
from (
  values 
    (date '2021-01-01'), 
    (date '2021-01-08'), 
    (date '2021-01-29')
) as v(date)
```

yields

```
date       | custom_week
-----------+------------
2021-01-01 |           1
2021-01-08 |           2
2021-01-29 |           5
```